# NSPredicate : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

I want to filter an array with NSPredicate and I have some issues with it.

I have an NSArray named "recipes" where are saved my data.

Here my code :

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];
    NSArray *searchRecipe = self.recipe[0];
    searchResults = [searchRecipe filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

When i run this code, i get the following error :

```
2014-01-20 15:40:16.729 Recipes Editor[909:60b] -[filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15666f80
2014-01-20 15:40:16.735 Recipes Editor[909:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15666f80'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f997f4b 0x39dd86af 0x2f99b8e7 0x2f99a1cb 0x2f8e94d8 0x12d01 0x12eeb 0x322fe3d9 0x3213f713 0x3213f6b3 0x3213f691 0x3212b11f 0x322fe149 0x321491cf 0x322bf261 0x322be807 0x322fdf77 0x322be525 0x302c67db 0x3214cdd9 0x322be453 0x32134a49 0x3037be9b 0x2f963183 0x2f962653 0x2f960e47 0x2f8cbc27 0x2f8cba0b 0x345f2283 0x3216f049 0x130c1 0x3a2e0ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Why filteredArrayUsingPredicate can't filter my array ?

thx

Comment: `self.recipe[0]` does not seem to be an `NSArray` itself. But turn on debugging information and the problem will disclose itself.

Comment: Is searchBeacon defined?

Comment: Yes, searchBeacon is a mistake. But i've got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method of NSArray like this:

```
    NSArray* filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    BOOL result = NO;

    // your evaluation code here

    return result;

}]];
```

The `evaluatedObject` is the current Object. You can easily check what class it is and validate everything you what. Just return YES if the `evaluatedObject` should stay after your evaluation or return NO if it should not included in the filtered array.

But be sure the array is an NSArray and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

`searchRecipe` doesn't appear to be an `NSArray`.  Add this debugging code:

```
NSArray *searchRecipe = self.recipe[0];
NSLog(@"searchRecipe type=%@", NSStringFromClass([searchRecipe class]));
searchResults = [searchRecipe filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Comment: I've got this error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: @semlh So the array is empty?!?

Comment: my fault, i forgot to put data in my app for testing. With Data in array i get this error : 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156b6a00'

And this log : searchBeacon type=ESTBeacon

Comment: @semlh And if you add the `NSLog()` line as I suggest, what does it say?

Comment: searchBeacon type=ESTBeacon EDIT: OK i get the error, thx for helping @trojanfoe

Comment: @semlh OK, so there you are.  Perhap you meant `searchResults = [self.recipe filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];` instead?

Comment: i've tested NSArray *searchBeacon = self.beacons; and i get the log : searchBeacon type=__NSArrayI

So i have to access to an object property in my array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes H2CO3 is said correctly your `self.recipe[0]` did not return you `NSArray` . You required debug your code either using breakpoint yeah following way

```
if([searchRecipe isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
   if(searchRecipe.count>0){
    searchResults = [searchRecipe filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
     }
    else{
       NSLog(@"array value %@", searchResults);
     }
  }
else{
 NSLog(@"Your return class isn't compatible");
}
```

This way you can avoid crashing thing.